# How to connect to postgres with two terminals?

Tags: postgresql

I have a terminal I can connect to postgres

```
psql testdb
```

but when I open a new tab or a new terminal and tried to connect to psql an error is returned

This error returns

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5433"?
```

I tried creating another user and using another port

```
createuser testing_multiple

psql -p 5433
```

the same error occurs.

Comment: There might be two different psql binaries (IOS?) Try to locate the psql binary (in both terminals) type `which psql`

Comment: I think both returns `/usr/bin/psql`

Comment: Maybe you are on two different machines? (or VMs) or in a chroot cage ...

Comment: umm, I am using `virtualenv` but even when I tried to workon the same virtualenv folder the new tab will still return the error

Comment: Why do you use a different portnumber (from the default 5432), do you have more than one instance of postgres installed and running?

Comment: I thought some other program was using the port, so I tried different port instead

Comment: Don't think. Verify. for example: `netstat -a | grep 5432`

Comment: Hmm, so it returns `b3ca3a93304c7997 stream      0      0 b3ca3a9330a54bef                0                0                0 /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432
`, I am not sure what does it mean

Comment: It probably means that your postgres installation is listening on the default port (5432)

Comment: So I found a way to fix it by `export PGHOST=localhost` putting this in my bashrc it works for every terminal I open, but I don't know why it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is probably that you're working within  `virtualenv`. It isn't a `chroot`, but it sets a bunch of environment variables to fake the local environment, quite likely including the `PATH` and other settings.

Most likely the unix socket is at a different location to that compiled into the `psql` binary you're using. I'd say your PostgreSQL server socket is probably actually at `/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5433`, in which case `export PGHOST=/tmp/` will work. Since you can connect from within the virtualenv terminal you can check though - within `psql`, run `SHOW unix_socket_directories;`. The location shown there is what you can give in `PGHOST` to connect to that PostgreSQL server.

The reason that `export PGHOST=localhost` works is that you are forcing `psql` (and other clients that use `libpq`) to connect over TCP/IP, instead of the default unix socket connection.